# Lightning Web Component: A required metadata folder named "lwc" does not exist in this workspace

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, visualstudiocode

I am trying to perform this(https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quick-start-lightning-web-components/create-a-hello-world-lightning-web-component) with VS code and it is throwing following error.
*A required metadata folder named "lwc" does not exist in this workspace.*

Performed following steps.

- Installed lightning web component plugin in VS code.
- Created a new SFDX project.
- Error while running SFDX: Create Lightning Web Component.

Comment: Did you signup for pre release org?

Comment: They didn't mention it anywhere, that it will work in spring 19 org only.

Comment: You missed this step in the trailhead where it says you need to create a prerelease org: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quick-start-lightning-web-components/set-up-salesforce-dx#-----------enable-dev-hub-in-a-developer-edition-pre-release-org----

Answer (score 16):

For now, you need to have the pre-release version installed for DX:

```
sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@pre-release
```

Make sure you've also updated all extensions, including [Lightning Web Components](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode-lwc), which is not currently part of the [Salesforce Extension Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode).

Often, simply restarting after installing/updating all extensions and the pre-release sfdx plugin will automatically create the lwc folder for you. You may also need to close and re-open the folder for it to take effect. I'm not sure how/why my lwc folder appeared, but it wasn't obvious as to what I did.

If all else fails, create a new project in a new, empty directory, and copy the lwc folder back into `force-app/main/default/`, so that it has two files:

```
./force-app/main/default/lwc/.eslintrc.json
./force-app/main/default/lwc/jsconfig.json
```

Once you've done that, you'll stop getting that error and be able to create new components. These config files may require modification if you copy from a new project, so make sure you check the file paths of jsconfig.json. Every time you create a new component with sfdx, jsconfig.json will be updated with more metadata, so make sure you commit this file if you're using a repo.

NOTE: Even though you'll be able to create files locally, to push to the server, you need a [pre-release org](https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/prerelease-spring19/) for now, since all new LWC features are tied to API 45.0 and later, while all production and scratch orgs will be 44.0.

Comment: Thanks. I think the above two files will automatically create when one could create lwc. No need to create them explicitly.

Comment: @AnuragBhardwaj They are *supposed* to be created, yes, but there was a bug back around when this question was asked (or, at least, it didn't work for me the first time). This is more of a "what happens when things go wrong" answer.

Answer (score 1):

You Just need to update the sfdx cli(global) Version : 
--> sfdx update
and update all extensions, including Lightning Web Components and Salesforce Extension Pack.
Close the visual code editor,Reopen it and try to create a new project it will automatically create the Lwc folder for you.