# Lightning Web Components: .eslintrc.json and jsconfig.json missing in lwc folder

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to implement this(https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quick-start-lightning-web-components/create-a-hello-world-lightning-web-component) with VS code. However, I am coming across the following roadblocks on 
sfdx: Create a Lightning Web Component:

1. Create a Lightning Web Component, the default directory name does not appear and I am not being able to point it to a particular directory
2. The above-mentioned files aren't getting created. I tried to create the files above explicitly, but it does not work.

Comment: Have you seen [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/242580)? Are you sure you're on version 45.0 with the latest plugins and extensions?

Comment: I had seen the post mentioned above. However,I uninstalled and installed VS Code and the issue got resolved! Thanks for getting back on this :-)

Comment: have you created sfdx:project first?

Comment: have you checked the version of your sfdx project? You should have version 45.0 in your sfdx project settings.